# System() call from a cgi script

Tags: html, web, cgi

For my assignment, I have a cgi script (C program) and a program that I want to call from the script using system(). Both in cgi-bin/ and chmodded to 755. I know that the system call I make in my cgi program is valid (the path is correct, the command is correct...) yet the call always fails. I checked the working directory during the execution of the cgi-script and it is correct. If I run the same call in bash it works, but in my menu program it doesn't work.

It's strange since the system call was working when I ran the server on my computer (using python -m CGIHTTPServer), but when I placed the website on my university's server which is where it has to be, everything works except for the system() call. So it seems like it has something to do with permissions.

Here's the call in question, if it's any help:

```
    sprintf(systemCall, "passweb -add %s", username);
    exitStatus = system(systemCall); //always 1
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the definition of `systemCall`, though I feel like you may need to do `systemCall = sprintf(systemCall, "passweb -add %s", username);` instead.

Comment: As a side comment: This might be an obvious security risk. I.e. if i write something like `$(rm -r .)` as the username, which will delete everything in the current directory (or I insert a worse script). This can be a reason why your University's computer does not allow this.

Comment: @BradMace `char systemCall[150] = {0};`

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek That does make sense, yet it is part of the assignment specification..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had to add a "./" in front of the executable path.

Like so: `sprintf(systemCall, "./passweb -add %s", username);`